# Remover virgula fora dos colchetes - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando remover a virgula que está localizada fora dos colchetes do seguinte trecho:

```
2||Azul||Cor||["#1983ff", "#1983ff"],3||Amarelo||Cor||["#fff73d"]
```

Preciso que o retorno, esteja dessa forma:

```
2||Azul||Cor||["#1983ff", "#1983ff"]3||Amarelo||Cor||["#fff73d"]
```

Algum ninja em regex pode me dar uma mão nisso? (O trecho acima não possui variação, sempre vira dessa maneira) Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer uma Expressão regular que selecione tudo menos a vírgula fora dos colchetes, ou selecione a vírgula fora dos colchetes e elimine a mesma?

Comment: @R.Santos Que selecione a vírgula fora dos colchetes e elimine-a.

Comment: E o padrão de pesquisa sempre será o do exemplo?

Comment: Sim, será o mesmo.

Comment: Você vai conseguir respostas mais corretas se nos disser o que no trecho que você postou varia. Quem sabe mais alguns exemplos?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, na verdade não tem muito o que acrescentar. Basicamente seria isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partindo o princípio que seu retorno terá esse formato, você pode simplemente:

```
var retorno =  string.replace("],","]");
```

Comment: Boa, agora ficou resolvido `+1`. `.split('],').join('')` também daria.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira mais simples de remover a vírgula, ignorando a regra dos colchetes na sentença, utilizando expressão regular, conforme abaixo, ele substitui: (vírgula + número) / primeira casa,
pelo (número) / segunda casa:

```
var string = '2||Azul||Cor||["#1983ff", "#1983ff"],3||Amarelo||Cor||["#fff73d"]';

var rtn = string.replace(/(,)([0-9]+)/gi,'$2');

console.log(rtn);
```